# Python: how do I hold all socket transfer while waiting for data?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a file transfer program between two sockets.

The sender has the usual game:

1. initiate file send
2. pick file to send, send filesize over socket.
3. pick recipient
4. confirm

Then the server reaches out to the recipient:

1. do you want to accept file of this filesize?
2. wait for y or n.

Recipient:

1. yes
2. receive.

and all the edge cases therein.

I am running a send thread and receive thread on both socket and server.
on the server I'm doing something like this.

```
import threading

accept_thread = Thread(target=accept)
send_thread = Thread(target=send)

def accept():
    while True:
        data = client.recv(BUFF)
        # break if no data
        if not data: break
        # if command is /sendfile
        if data == b'/sendfile':

            # get filesize
            filesize = client.recv(BUFF)

            # get recipient
            recipient = client.recv(BUFF)
        
            # check if recipient is in address list. 
            if recipient_exists(recipient):
                sender_socket.send(b'valid')
        
            ask = recipient_socket.send(b'Do you want to accept?')

            if ask == 'n':
                sender_socket.send(b'rejected')

            else:
                data = sender_socket.recv(BUFF)
                recipient_socket.send(data)
    
        msg = data
        clients.send(msg.encode())
```

Needless to say, things somehow go out of whack. I keep getting my sendfile tagged onto the end of whatever I send. For instance, if I send a text file, the last bytes will always be '/sendfile'.

And if the sender types anything when they're not supposed to, then that gets added to the file transfer as well.

What do I need to use in order to make this work? I tried putting a thread lock before the receive.

Edit: Here is my send and receive:

````
   def xfer_file(self, path, server_socket):
        """Opens file at path, sends to server_socket."""

        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            server_socket.sendfile(f, 0, self.filesize)

    def receive_file(self, data, BUFFSIZE, filesize, client):
        """Download file transfer from server."""

        try:
            data = client.recv(BUFFSIZE)
            bytes_recd = len(data)
            print("STARTING=========")

            # target_path = self._set_target_path()

            with open('image(2).jpg', 'wb') as f:
                while bytes_recd < int(filesize):
                    f.write(data)
                    data = client.recv(BUFFSIZE)
                    bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(data)
                    print(bytes_recd)
                    print(data)
                    if data == b'':
                        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")

        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("FINISHED==========")
    ```
````

Comment: You need to make sure that when receiving the file data you read exactly and only the number of bytes that were advised ahead of the file. This is done by adjusting the receive buffer size when you get to what should be the last read. Otherwise you will read the following command as well.

Comment: And you certainly don' t need to 'hold all socket transfer while waiting for data'.

Comment: in my send function, it's fairly straightforward, but still I get concatenation of previous transmissions at the end.  at the end.

`
def xfer_file(self, path, server_socket):
        """Opens file at path, sends to server_socket."""

        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            server_socket.sendfile(f, 0, self.filesize)
`

Comment: I've already answered all that.